# Spark word2vec findSynonyms on Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use `findSynonyms` operation without `collecting` (action). Here is an example. I have a `DataFrame` which holds vectors.

```
df.show()

+--------------------+
|              result|
+--------------------+
|[-0.0081423431634...|
|[0.04309031420520...|
|[0.03857229948043...|
+--------------------+
```

I want to use `findSynonyms` on this `DataFrame`. I tried

```
df.map{case Row(vector:Vector) => model.findSynonyms(vector)}
```

but it throws null pointer exception. Then I've learned, spark does not support nested transformations or actions. One possible way to do is collecting this `DataFrame` and run `findSynonyms` then. How can I do this operation on `DataFrame` level?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you want to perform a function on each row in the `DataFrame`. To do that, you can declare a User Defined Function (UDF). In your case the UDF will take a vector as input.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val func = udf((vector: Vector) => {model.findSynonyms(vector)})
df.withColumn("synonymes", func($"result"))
```

A new column "synonymes" will be created using the results from the `func` function.